# PHP realpath not work at Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: php, input-type-file, realpath

I've PHP code like that

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="file" name="asdf">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php
$file = $_POST['asdf'];
$file2 = realpath($file);
$file3 = str_replace('\\','/',$file2);
echo $file3;
?>
```

I'm stuck at when I using IE to run this script ex I choose `file = 'D:\myfolder\folder1\filename.txt'` the code isn't going error. But when I using Firefox or Chrome, there are nothing giving me result.

Comment: Because you are not allowed to access the file system like that

Comment: Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php.

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` your code should generate errors in all browsers

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly, I've try to add the display_errors but result not giving me an error report.
here my script
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$filee = $_POST['namafile'];
$aaa = realpath($filee);

$bbb = str_replace('\\','/', $aaa);

echo "1. ",$bbb ."<br>2. ". $filee;
?>

in the IE giving me results :
1. C:/Users/40702505/Documents/asd.txt
2. C:\Users\40702505\Documents\asd.txt

but Chrome just blank

Comment: @JohnConde in IE the code is running well, but i still not get the core why at chrome & firefox are show me nothing

Comment: The PHP code runs on the server, not in IE, Firefox or Chrome. It produces the same result, no matter what browser do you use to see it. If its output looks different in different browsers it means the output is invalid HTML; each browser is allowed to fix it as it thinks it's better (but none of them could read your mind, though).